# Rails syntax error, but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting:

```
 syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end diamond.send(field) = fields[field]
```

But I don't see why though. I am trying to dynamically assigning values.

Here is the code:

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      diamond = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new

      fields = row.to_hash

      # assign non float attributes to columns
      ['cust_ref', 'ags_1st_number', 'ags_ending_number', 'gold_cut_grade', 
      'polish_grade', 'symmetry_grade', 'color_grade', 'fluor_desc', 
      'clarity_grade', 'girdle_min_max_percentage', 'diameter_min_max', 
      'girdle_condition', 'proportion_grade', 'comment_1', 'comment_2', 
      'comment_3', 'comment_4', 'is_non_ideal', 'key_to_symbols', 'shape'].each do |field|
     diamond.send(field) = fields[field]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to write `diamond.send(field + '=', fields[field])` I think.. Because the way you are assigning is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are calling the getter and not the setter.

To use `send`, you need to distinguish between the attr_accessor's given methods.
So, for example:

```
class Test
   attr_accessor :field
end

t = Test.new

t.send(:field)
#=> nil
t.send(:field=, 'lalala')
#=>'lalala'
t.send(:field)
#=>'lalala'
```

And this works with strings too.

[EDIT] As mentioned by @jordan, this also allows you to do string interpolation, using or not symbols. 
So the next lines would also work:

```
a = 'field='
t.send(:"#{a}", 'lalala')
t.send(a)
b = 'field'
t.send("#{b}=", 'lalala')
```

And so on.

Comment: Important to note that if you have the name of the attribute (e.g. `"field"` or `:field`) in a variable, you can add the equals sign using ordinary string (or symbol) interpolation: `t.send(:"#{attr_name}=", 'lalala')`.

Comment: @Jordan `"#{attr_name}="` is enough... why that has to be preceded by `:` ?

Comment: Because symbols are the ruby way, in the way I see it. They're more memory efficient and can be used in most of the places where you would usually use a string.

@Jordan, you are absolutely right. Should've pointed that. I'll edit my answer to keep that clear.

Comment: `"#{attr_name}="` evaluates a string whereas `:"#{attr_name}"` evaluates to a symbol. `send` will take either, although IIRC in old versions of Ruby it took only symbols. In practice it doesn't make much of a difference, so it's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: @Jordan... `ob.send(:name=, 12)`  or `ob.send("name=", 12)` is fine.. But `ob.send(:"name=", 12)` doesn't make any sense.. I am not getting your point..

Comment: @ArupRakshit To do interpolation in a symbol you need the quotation marks. If `attr_name` has a value of `"foo"`, then `:"#{attr_name}="` evaluates to the symbol `:foo=`. `:#{attr_name}=` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Jordan Makes sense now.. If *version of Ruby* don't support `#send` with first *argument as a string*, then only `:"#{attr}="` is needed to do.. otherwise not.. Perfect, got now what you meant to say..

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto It's true that symbols are more memory-efficient in certain circumstances (e.g. when you have a lot of duplicate strings that are in different places in memory, although copy-on-write in Ruby 2.0 mitigates this a lot). However it's important to remember that they're never garbage-collected, and so can become a problem if, say, you have code creating lots of long symbols with different names. There was even a Rails vulnerability relating to this, because its YAML parser automatically instantiated symbols of arbitrary length. Symbols are great, but they're not a silver bullet.

Comment: @Jordan, I didn't know that. I don't abuse them, but it is always good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are proposing is not a valid assignment syntax in Ruby.

You can define assignment methods in Ruby (check http://joeyates.info/2012/01/16/ruby-bareword-assignment-and-method-calls-with-implicit-self/ for a more deep-in explanation of assignment).

```
class Diamond
  def proportion_grade=(arg)
    @proportion_grade = arg
  end
end
```

If you declared an attr writer or accessor, this is done for you

```
class Diamond
  attr_accessor :proportion_grade
end
```

so what you want to call is the method `proportion_grade=`, not really `proportion_grade`

the correct way would be:

```
['all', 'those', 'arguments'].each do |field|
   diamond.send("#{field}=", fields[field])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `diamond.send(field)` is a method and you shouldn't treat a method call like a variable that is being declared.  Declare another variable if you want to save `fields[field]` as a variable.  Delete the "= fields[field] from the line and just put `diamond.send(field)` on its own line, or `diamond.send(field + '=' + fields[field])` as per @Arup Rakshit.